# jsPDF server side usage

Tags: google-apps-script, jspdf

I really like the look of jsPDF but I can't seem to find any documentation for server side usage. The page [here](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) seems to suggest that this is possible, but the link for an example is broken or no longer exists. I would really like to use this library in a Google Apps Script project if possible.

Comment: @Bobrovsky - just curious as to why this isn't relevant to "PDF generation is the process of creating a PDF document using various tools or libraries"

Comment: you are having difficulties with jsPdf. It's, in a sense, related to PDF and PDF generation. But not more than it's related to "documentation", "server", "page", "links", "example", "library" or "script".

Comment: If you are looking for a server side pdf builder, I would consider using a different program call FPDF. It is built in php, and will give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The new home for jsPDF is [here](http://jspdf.com/). Note that the "Server-side will work anywhere" promise is no longer presented. Chances are that it would work on Node.js, for example, but since Apps-Script is an incomplete javascript implementation it might not work there.

You can generate PDF files from within Apps-Script already. If the subject document is in Google Drive, then you can use `getAs("application/pdf")` to request the document as a PDF. (If it's not a Google Drive document, then first turn it into one.) Read over [4 ways to do Mail Merge using Google Apps Script](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2011/10/4-ways-to-do-mail-merge-using-google.html), method 3, for an example.

Comment: I use `getAs()` now - I just really wish it were more robust. For example, I really need the ability to combine pages into one PDF. Thanks for the links.

Comment: In that case, you will be interested in [Issue 699](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=699), which is a request to add the ability to modify pdf files.